# What stops someone from forging a password reset link?

Tags: php, security, passwords, md5

I'm creating a profile system for a website, and I'm at the point where I'm coding the password reset function in PHP.

Basically, I'm asking the user for their email address, then setting a random md5 password and emailing this to them and it comes in a link formatted like

www.mysite.com/reset.php?email=myemail@myemail.com&hash=hashgoeshere

What is the point in hiding passwords behind md5 when someone could just forge a password reset link and use the hash value instead of the password?

Comment: *"then setting a random md5 password"* - don't use MD5 and don't use that method of passing the password in a URL. Use a one-time and random key, that they will then enter a new password. This doesn't "answer" the question, but it's a "don't do this" comment.

Comment: The hash in the URL should not be the hashed password. On the other hand, you should not directly reset a password for a user without sending them a confirmation email first. Someone can use another user's email and then keep resetting their password.
The proper way to do it is to send the user an email with a confirmation link to reset their password. This link would contain the hash as a form of checking that authenticity of the link.Ex: `md5($email. 'someSecretH3re' . $userId);`.This way you can reconstruct the hash when the user clicks the link and compare both hashes (generated and email)

Comment: That till doesn't prevent fraud though, a MySQL injection will easily steal the one time code. Anyone could reset anyone elses password without having to have access to the email address used.

Comment: that''s where you need to prevent against that and using a time limitation on the reset key ^

Comment: as @Adon said. Plus, if the user did not make the request, can simply be told to ignore the request and the key gets automatically deleted running a daily cron job to delete keys older than a given timeset.

Comment: I sure hope you don't continue using MD5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should opt for a workflow like:

- Generate a new GUID, save it against the user account, call it PasswordResetToken
- The email you send should redirect the user to /reset.php?email=myemail@email.com&resetToken=XXXXXXXXXXX
- You verify that the reset token exists for the user account specified
- Ask the user to enter a new password of their choice and save it.
- Nullify the saved reset token so it cannot be used again

It would be extremely/statistically unlikely anyone could then guess a link to set someone's password to what they chose, unless (a) a reset request was really made for that account, and (b) they can happen to guess a GUID that you generated.

Comment: with this method nobody can reset other password unless he don't know that token value..and a user can choose new password of his own.

Comment: Let's just hope that the OP doesn't ask for code, after the fact ;-)

Comment: It might also be prudent to store only a hash of the token in the database (`sha256` is fine here) and compare with `hash_equals()`. Also, make sure your "GUID" is generated from a CSPRNG.

Comment: You should also limit the lifespan of the reset token. Store a timestamp with it so that you can fail if the user comes back days or weeks later.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you should not send the hash of the token (or even a password) in the link, instead send a random **token**:

```
http://www.example.com/reset.php?token=78dk3hi3479s8j383o98u3
```

In the database you store a **hash** of the token together with the user id. Now when the user clicks the link, you get the token and can calculate the hash of this token again. If it matches with a stored hash in the database, then you can allow the user to reset his password.

Since an attacker must send the original token, and you calculate the hash on the server side, he cannot forge a valid token. This also protects the token in case the attacker has read access to the database (SQL-injection).